# change EditText's background color without clearing the border color

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I change EditText's background color without clearing the border?
If I call `editText.setBackgroundColor(color)` the orange border around the editText disappears..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new style xml, and use it with the help of

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourstylename);
```